# NVIDIA driver causes black screen and PC freeze (only in-game)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, freeze, gpu

I downloaded Fortnite 2 months ago. I've had freezing problems with it ever since then

It's way more stable if I play it at 60fps, but even then it crashes. 120fps is just unplayable as it always freezes. However, my machine runs the game perfectly.

I've tried everything - did a clean re-install of the GPU driver, reinstalled Windows 10, installed motherboard drivers, changed settings in the NVIDIA control panel 3D section. I probably did a lot more but I can't remember it all.

Recently, I tried installing an old NVIDIA game driver, because I read up somewhere that the new drivers can cause the freeze. So I downloaded the 381.78 driver and installed it right after a clean OS install - it still crashed.

I contacted Epic Games about the problem and they said the GPU is causing the problem, that it's a known issue, and they are working with NVIDIA on it.

[**Piriform Speccy results**](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/wyqIMBseo6aQKiwOqoW4Ms7)

Graphics card info:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If both the game dev and nvidia is working on it... errr.... not sure there's anything that anyone can do?

Comment: I havent seen anyone have this problem on Windows 7. Also, it's a known problem that nvidia new drivers can cause freeze. But if you find a good old one it might help.. i dont know.

Comment: Recently updated to Windows 7 64 bit, didnt help the problem at all.